# Funds transfer pricing for loans

Tags: funds, banking

I wonder if the $FTP\%$ term for loans in the following formula

$$FTP\%=\text{BaseRate} + \alpha
 \,\text{LP}_{1y}+(1-\alpha) \,\text{LP}_{6m},$$

where $\text{LP}$ is a liquidity premium, is a measure for the bank's profit?

Comment: FTP% is the cost of the funds to the bank, they lend money out to customers at a rate higher than this (I hope) and the difference is their profit. The cost of funds for a bank is like the Cost of Goods Sold for a shop.

Comment: Thanks, so a lower FTP% is better? Is it possible to have a FTP rate of 50%? @noob2

Comment: Yes, I don't know where you got this 50% but it seems much too high.